# Understanding the difference between "different iid random variables" and "different instance of same random variable"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability, independence

In the derivation of unbiased [sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator), it is considered that $X_i$ are iid random variables while $X_i$ actually represents a sample from a population. So my question is that shouldn't we consider $X_i$ to be an instance of same random variable whose probability distribution is probability of selecting $X_i$ ?

For example, consider I have population of people with different heights and I select a sample of people from this population. This sampling of people can be thought of a repetitive procedure of sampling a value from a random variable i.e uniform r.v. Isn't it so?

Also I have generally seen it that when we consider samples of a stochastic process, we model each sample as i.i.d instead of repetitive sampling (taking multiple values) from the stochastic process. For example in the definition of strict [sense stochastic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) we say that the joint distribution of different samples of $X_t$ will be same whether we sample it at any time. Here my question will be rephrased as how can we have joint distribution of constant numbers? Like if I have a series of dice-face-numbers then there is no meaning of considering joint probability distribution of these numbers?

Comment: The first two question you pose... I've asked myself the same questions multiple times. I think I even posted some sort of question here but I am not sure about that. Treating these $X_i$ as different random variables even though i.i.d. ones... it's just somehow counter intuitive to me.

Comment: But also... I am pretty sure that there's no such thing as "different instance of same random variable"

Comment: Here are several related questions: [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455773/are-elements-of-a-sample-i-i-d-realizations-of-the-same-random-variable-or-real), [Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429350/difference-between-mean-for-samples-and-mean-for-random-variable). [Q3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3819760/estimation-of-a-r-v-in-presence-of-multiple-data-points-observations-measuremen).

Comment: Thanks @d.k.o. I think following threads cleared my understanding.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760048/what-is-a-sample-of-a-random-variable
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141416/example-of-sample-x-1-x-2-ldots-x-n?rq=1
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324984/terminology-regarding-random-sample
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084035/confused-about-the-definition-of-a-random-sample-statistics-and-estimators-esti?rq=1
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429350/difference-between-mean-for-samples-and-mean-for-random-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: In short, the word "sample" is used differently depending upon the context. Sometimes it's is used as a realization of a random variable (which I was thinking). But most of the times a sample of size n of a r.v $X$ is actually a collection of n independent r.v $X_i$ which have identical distribution as that of $X$. 
The context depends on your experiment. It usually means collection of values(realization) in a survey context where you collect a survey i.e you are actually recording values and means a collection random variables where you randomly select samples from a population. (1/3)

Comment: For example if an experiment is such that I toss a coin 2 times (or tossed two coins simultaneously) and record values according to face of coin then the recorded values will be a sample(member) from the population {00,11,01,10}. Now If I say that I tossed a coin two times (or tossed two coins simultaneously) then a sample can be represented as $X_1$, $X_2$ where $X_i$ is a Bernoulli random variable. (2/3)

Comment: If a say that I RANDOMLY select (or observe) an element of population n times where the probability distribution of selecting the element is given by random variable $X$ then it always means that a sample is collection of n iid random variables. Hope it helps! (3/3)

Comment: Such questions typically get better answers over at cross validated. Here are some posts there to consider: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440519/differences-between-realization-of-the-random-variable-and-deterministic-variabl  (and a lot of similar). Maybe it is better to go to the conceptual foundation in the concept of *exchangeable* see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344794/exchangeability-and-iid-random-variables,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233259/why-are-words-in-a-document-for-bag-of-words-model-exchangeable-but-not-independ,

Comment: ... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207162/simple-question-on-exchangeability, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3520/can-someone-explain-the-concept-of-exchangeability, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/447383/is-independence-subjective  and then continue search on CV (or maybe here?) for post on exchangeability (and the deFinetti Theorem.)